# How to scan for increase in values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function where if I input a list of numbers, e.g. `values = [10, 20, 40, 30, 15]`, it compares the values left to right and returns true if it is increasing by more than a certain amount.

```
def incr(values, diff):
    i = 0
    diff = int(diff)
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        if values[i] - values[i+1] < diff:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I keep on getting False no matter what I do.

Comment: Sounds like you want the _difference_ between the two values to be less than `diff`?

Comment: Yes @PranavHosangadi! Sorry didn't make it very clear

Comment: Then why are you using `+`?

Comment: Well then why do you check `values[i] + values[i+1]`? Also please redo a tutorial on functions and the `return` statement. `return` causes execution to return out of the function to its caller. This is easy to catch if you [step through your program in a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953).

Comment: Sorry typed it up in a rush, meant to be -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you have to use `-`.

Second thing is that the function returns before checking all values in the for loop, so change your function to this -

```
def incr(values, diff):
    i = 0
    diff = int(diff)
    
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        if values[i+1] - values[i] > diff: # Notice here that I have changed '<' to '>'
           return False

    return True
```

Result:

```
values = [10, 20, 30,40]
d = 10

print(incr(values,d)) # True


values = [10, 20, 40, 30, 15]
print(incr(values,d)) # False
```

Comment: it should be `values[i+1] - values[i]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix of your code, you had several mistakes.

1. you were not calculating a difference but a sum (`values[i] - values[i+1]`), in the edit the difference was in the wrong order
2. Once you return, your code is over, you should return only True at the end

```
def incr(values, diff):
    diff = int(diff)
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        if values[i+1] - values[i] < diff:
            return False
    return True
```

Here is a (slower) alternative using list comprehension (I set diff=5):

```
all([values[i+1]>values[i]+5 for i in range(len(values)-1)])
```

Comment: `Once you return, your code is over, you should save the values and return only at the end` not necessarily, the algorithm is to find if all values are increasing so in case there is one false case it's wise to get out of loop right away because last result would definitely be false. i guess this is how all() function itself is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def incr(values, diff):
    diff = int(diff)            
    ret_bool = all(values[i+1] - values[i] > diff for i in range(len(values)-1))
    return ret_bool

print(incr([10, 20, 40, 30, 15], 9))
# False
print(incr([10, 20, 40, 50, 65], 9))
# True
```

Comment: @Jojo, I think this is your answer of your question, am I correct

Comment: Thank you so so much!